# How to format R data.frame output?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let me start by saying I am brand new to R, so any solution with a detailed explanation would be appreciated so I can learn from it.

I have a set of csv files with the following rows of information:

"ID" "Date" "A" "B" (where A and B are some data points)

I am attempting to get the output in a meaningful manner and am stuck on what I am missing.

```
observations <- funtion(dir, id= 1:10){
  #get all file names in a vector
  all_files <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  #get the subset of files we want to read
  file_contents <- lapply(all_files[id], read.csv)
  #cbind the file contents
  output <- do.call(rbind, file_contents)
  #remove all NA values
  output <- output[complete.cases(output), ]

  #at this point output is a data.frame so display the output
  table(output[["ID"]])
}
```

My current output is :

```
2    4    8   10  12
1000 500 200 150 100
```

which is correct but I need it in column form so it can be understood by looking at it. The output I am trying to get to is below:

```
   id obs_total
 1  2 1000
 2  4  500
 3  8  200
 4 10  150
 5 12  100
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can use `as.data.frame(table(output[["ID"]]))`.

Comment: @danas.zuokas since output is already a data frame is there an easier way than converting to a table and then back to a data frame? In this case I need to rename the column for obs_total because it is a titleless column otherwise

Comment: ok I figured out how to rename the columns after using as.data.frame. I used: colnames(output) <- c("ID", "obs_total")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` outputs a contingency table. You want a data frame. You can wrap `as.data.frame(...)` around you output to convert it.

```
as.data.frame(table(ID = output[["ID"]]))
```

Comment: output is already a data frame. would there be a shorter way? In the case of the output I am taking many rows and "condensing" them by ID with the total number of observations

Comment: Your data frame is a data frame, but `table` outputs a contingency table (it's a fancy matrix). I don't know what your definition of "short" is, but it's hard to imagine a world where 20 extra characters of code on line isn't short enough.

Comment: I'm learning so I simply meant, if I don't convert it to a table first, can I do the same thing in fewer lines

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers are correct, looks like you have everything you need, just transpose the data frame. Try this:

```
mat<-matrix(round(runif(10),3),nrow=2)
df<-as.data.frame(mat)
colnames(df)=c("1","2","3","4","5")
t(df)
```

Comment: sorry dan. I hadn't updated my test data in the question. I don't need the round function.